# Entire Logic App workflow run is marked as "Failed" because on action fails, even though dependent actions succeed

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

[image]

The whole story is pretty much in that screenshot. You can see my condition evaluates to true, and I call another action successfully. Yet the run history is marked as "Failed".

This is bad because Log Analytic queries because really ugly if I have to parse stuff like that out.

**I set a termination action of success under the final action and that worked, but i do not want to have to do that. To me, it is a bug that the entire workflow is marked as a failure.**

Is this a bug? Do I need to wrap things in scope first? Am I misusing the condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how the Logic App behaves. When an error is not caught the Logic App run is considered as failed.

In order to handle this "try-catch" problem wrap your "*UpdateUser HTTP POST*" and "*Delete message...*" actions in a scope. Put the condition "*If user was not found by username*" just after the scope and **Configure run after** settings of the condition to **has failed** (and eventually also to **has timed out**). That should ensure correct error handling.

Note: You can also wrap your condition in another scope "Error handling scope" so the Logic App will be more readable.

Comment: When you say more readable, do you mean from the JSON view standpoint? If anything I want the least amount of wrappers and conditions in a logic app.